# Find the bound $||z(t)||\leq \epsilon_z(t)$, where $z(t) = \int_0^t He^{A(t-s)}B\omega(s)ds$, $\omega(s)$ is bounded and $A,H,B$ constant matrices.

Tags: matrices, calculus-of-variations, control-theory, optimal-control, linear-control

I am looking for an alternative solution (or just some helpful comments) to this problem:

Let $\omega(t)\in\mathbb{R}^q$, $q\in\mathbb{N}$, be a absolutely continous function satisfying: $0<||\omega(t)||\leq \epsilon_{\omega},\, \forall t\geq 0$. Let $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, $q\leq n\in\mathbb{N}$, be a Hurwitz matrix (all its eigenvalues are strictly less than zero); and let $H\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ , $n\geq m\in\mathbb{N}$ and $B\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times q}$.

Then, find $\epsilon_z(t)>0$ such that, $||z(t)||\leq \epsilon_z(t)$ for all $t\geq 0$, where

\begin{equation}
z(t) = \int_0^t He^{A(t-s)}B\,\omega(s)ds.
\end{equation}

$z(t)$ is bounded as matrix $A$ is Hurwitz.

My first way to find the value of $\epsilon_z(t)$ was by just taking the norm of $z(t)$ and applying straightforward algebra:
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
||z(t)|| = \left\vert\left\vert\int_0^t He^{A(t-s)}B\,\omega(s)ds,\right\vert\right\vert \leq \int_0^t \left\vert\left\vert He^{A(t-s)}B\,\omega(s)\right\vert\right\vert ds\leq \mu(t)\epsilon_{\omega}\triangleq \epsilon_z(t)
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

where $\mu(t)\triangleq \int_0^t \left\vert\left\vert He^{A(t-s)}B \right\vert\right\vert ds$.

However, I am worried about the conservativeness of this value of $\epsilon_z(t)$. In fact, for a given fixed $t$, I need to find the less conservative bound. I think that this is a more complex solution as it implies, not only to find $\epsilon_z(t)$, but also to assure that there exist some $\omega(t)$ causing that $||z(t)||=\epsilon_z(t)$.

¿Does my analysis guarantee that there exist some $\omega(t)$ that forces the equality?. If not, ¿Could this problem be addressed in other way?.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: In the scalar case ($q=m=1$) when $H\,e^{A\,t}\,B$ never changes sign the inequality would be equal when $\omega(t)$ is constant. However, I am not sure if this could be generalized for larger $q$ or $m$.

Comment: Note that $z(t)$ is the solution to the differential equation: $$\begin{align*}\dot{x}(t)&=Ax(t)+B \omega(t)\\ z(t)&=Hx(t)\end{align*}$$ with $x(0)=0$. Since $A$ is Hurwitz, the system is exponentially stable, hence it is BIBO stable. There should be a large amount of literature for output signal bounds of BIBO systems, but I'm not familiar with it.